# ADFS 2016 Error MSIS7065 No registered handlers on path adfs/oauth2/token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, adfs

I'm trying to acquire a JWT token from my ADFS using client credentials flow.
Applications groups are configured, sign in page is reachable using a web browser but when I try to get my token using postman I get an error in the event viewer.

Request :

```
POST /adfs/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=client-2
&client_secret= zr7D6oIXNgN1BCO6wZkBM5WrWpzr-dBzhW3z0NsX
&grant_type=client_credentials
&resource= https://localhost:3030
```

Event viewer event :

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token to process the incoming request.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Tried to google it but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Was this farm upgraded from server 2012R2?

Check if the "/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration" endpoint is available using below command.

Get-AdfsEndpoint -AddressPath "/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration"

If you get output similar to below contact Microsoft support for help.

```
PS C:\> Get-AdfsEndpoint -AddressPath "/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration"
 
Get-AdfsEndpoint : PS0137: No Endpoint found with Address '/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AdfsEndpoint -AddressPath "/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AdfsEndpoint], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PS0137,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.GetEndpointCommand
```